# Compare two object to generate a third one

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have two objects:

Object 1:

```
{[ 'Managers', 'Employee', '50% Discount', undefined, 'Managers', undefined ]}
```

Object 2:

```
{[ { id: 3, name: 'Managers', transaction_modifier: 1 },
  { id: 4, name: 'Employee', transaction_modifier: 1.1 },
  { id: 12, name: '50% Discount', transaction_modifier: 0.5 } ]}
```

I need to compare both objects and create a new one:

if Object 1 match Object 2's name return

```
{id: objectID, name: ObjectName, transaction_modifier: ObjectTransaction_modifier}
```

if object one is undefined or name not in Object 2 return

```
{id: null, name: null, transaction_modifier: 1}
```

In this example I expect to return the following object:

```
[ { id: 3, name: 'Managers', transaction_modifier: 1 },
  { id: 4, name: 'Employee', transaction_modifier: 1.1 },
  { id: 12, name: '50% Discount', transaction_modifier: 0.5 },
  { id: null, name: null, transaction_modifier: 1 },
  { id: 3, name: 'Managers', transaction_modifier: 1 },
  { id: null, name: null, transaction_modifier: 1 }]
```

Comment: Please show what research you've done and any attempts you've made to solve the issue yourself. Also, the beginning "objects" are not well formed. If they are arrays, they should just have `[ ... contents ... ]`, no wrapping `{ }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```js
const fields = [ 'Managers', 'Employee', '50% Discount', undefined, 'Managers', undefined ];

const data = [ { id: 3, name: 'Managers', transaction_modifier: 1 },
  { id: 4, name: 'Employee', transaction_modifier: 1.1 },
  { id: 12, name: '50% Discount', transaction_modifier: 0.5 } ];

console.log(fields.map(field => data.find(entry => entry.name === field) || ({id: null, name: null, transaction_modifier: 1})));
```